# using font awsome unicode in react, I am trying to ADD A icon in placeholder using unicode in react

Tags: reactjs, icons, font-awesome

```
<Form.Control
  type="text"
  style={{ fontFamily: 'fontawesome' }}
  placeholder="&#xf622; Enter name of your driving school"
  className="px-3 py-2 w-100"
  onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setDrivingSchoolName(event.target.value);
}}
/>
```

I want to use fontawsome unicode in this placeholder of an input tag so that I can get that icon in the UI .. like we can use in Normal html file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.